# Chapter and section numbering style

Tags: color, numbering, titles, tikz-styles, boxes

I am writing a document in LaTeX and I would like to use exactly the numbering style as shown in the image attached to my message.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hello, please include a minimal example.